# What is the word used to describe a question that demands one of two possible answers?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, rhetoric

Politicians seem incapable of giving a straight answer when posed simple questions, sometimes because the question being asked simply cannot be dignified by a one word answer, other times because they are trying desperately to avoid revealing an ulterior motive or cock-up. 
But what do you call this kind of question?

For example:

Q: Is my t-shirt white or black? 
A: White

Q: Theresa, did you know about a reported failed Trident test when you addressed parliament during a debate on the renewal of Britain’s nuclear deterrent?
A: Well, errr, I believe that..... strong and  stable....

Answer (score 6):

**Binary** inherently means that there are only two options available (bi = two)

From the OED:

> [**Binary**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/binary)
>   adjective
>
> 1. Relating to, composed of, or involving two things.
> 2. Relating to, using, or denoting a system of numerical notation that has 2 rather than 10 as a base.

A **binary question** therefore only has 2 possible answers.

There are similar terms for a different amount of answers. Ternary = 3 options to choose from. However, these are very rare. Ternary is only very rarely used; the others even less so.

---

**HOWEVER**

From context, you seem to mean "a question to which the answers are strictly defined and cannot be vague".
In this context, I would call it a **clear-cut question**.

> [**Clear-cut**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/clear-cut)
>   adjective
>
> 1. Sharply defined; easy to perceive or understand.
>      *‘we now had a clear-cut objective’*

This doesn't inherently mean that there are two possible answers, but it does mean that the answers are very strictly defined and not up for discussion.

Comment: It's also commonly called a "binary choice".

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking for a ***[polar question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes%E2%80%93no_question)***?

> In linguistics, a yes–no question, formally known as a polar question,
>   is a question whose expected answer is either "yes" or "no". Formally,
>   they present an exclusive disjunction, a pair of alternatives of which
>   only one is acceptable.

There's lots more interesting info in the Wikipedia article.